# Viewing dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function init() {
        document.getElementById("inputname").id = 'newinputname';
        document.getElementById("newinputname").onchange = function() { Test() };
      }
      function Test() {
        alert('Test');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload='init()'>
    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="inputname">
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't to seem to find any way of viewing the altered page. For example in the above example, which has no purpose other than to illustrate, I would like to be able to see the effect of the `onchange` reflected. With say IE and <kbd>F12</kbd> tools I can see the name change to the input element but can't see the `onchange` anywhere.

I have a piece of code which alters a table significantly, changes `id`s and sets `onclick` handlers. I would like to check that the changes have gone through. As above I can see the `id` alterations etc have worked OK and the `onclick` functions seem to work OK but I can't see where the `onclick="..."` has been entered in the new page output.

I think I may have some basic misunderstanding. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You can't see the change in HTML because you're not changing the HTML.

Comment: Perhaps you should just try to call the function Test() when onChange is invoked. Something like: `document.getElementById("newinputname").onchange=Test();`

Comment: @Abhay: You mean `...onchange=Test`.  With the parentheses, the function gets run immediately, and its return value will be what JS tries (and, almost certainly, fails) to set as the event handler.  Either way, though, the effect on the HTML will be roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding attribute onchange, assigning `document.getElementById("newinputname").onchange` sets new event listener.

If you want to see events connected to element, you will have to use `console.log` and similar tools. See this answer: [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106)